# how to get a parent ID in child entity object in typeorm + nestjs

Tags: mysql, nestjs, typeorm, typeorm-activerecord

I have a simple relation company has many projects and everything is super fine, when I get the result `parent ID` is missing from entity object while its present in query

Company Entity :

```
@Entity()
export class Company {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ unsigned: true })
    id: number;

    @Column({ nullable: false })
    name: string;

    @Column({
        type: 'datetime',
        nullable: false,
        default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP',
    })
    created_at;

    @Column({ nullable: true, type: 'datetime' })
    updated_at;

    @OneToMany(
        type => Project,
        project => project.company
    )
    project: Project[];

}
```

Project Entity :

```
@Entity()

export class Project {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ unsigned: true })
    id: number;


    @Column({ nullable: false })
    name: string;

    @ManyToOne(
        type => Company,
        company => company.project,
        { nullable: false }
    )
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'company_id' })
    company: Company;


    @Column({
        type: 'datetime',
        nullable: false,
        default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP',
    })
    created_at;

    @Column({ nullable: true, type: 'datetime' })
    updated_at;


}
```

Query in service :

```
return this.companyRepository.find({ where: { id: 1 }, relations: ['project'] })
```

Query log is :

```
SELECT 
    `Company`.`id` AS `Company_id`,
    `Company`.`name` AS `Company_name`,
    `Company`.`created_at` AS `Company_created_at`,
    `Company`.`updated_at` AS `Company_updated_at`,
    `Company__project`.`id` AS `Company__project_id`,
    `Company__project`.`name` AS `Company__project_name`,
    `Company__project`.`created_at` AS `Company__project_created_at`,
    `Company__project`.`updated_at` AS `Company__project_updated_at`,
    `Company__project`.`company_id` AS `Company__project_company_id`
FROM
    `company` `Company`
        LEFT JOIN
    `project` `Company__project` ON `Company__project`.`company_id` = `Company`.`id`
WHERE
    `Company`.`id` = 1;
```

but when i print result my company object contains `project` array but in project array company_id is missing or typeorm has excluded it while creating an object, is there any way than i can get parent_id which is company_id in project object

Result :

```
Company {
  id: 1,
  name: 'company',
  created_at: 2020-10-24T18:46:59.000Z,
  updated_at: null,
  project: [
    Project {
      id: 1,
      name: 'project 1',
      created_at: 2020-10-24T18:47:35.000Z,
      updated_at: null
    },
    Project {
      id: 2,
      name: 'project 2',
      created_at: 2020-10-24T19:08:08.000Z,
      updated_at: null
    }
  ]
}
```

expected result :

```
Company {
  id: 1,
  name: 'company',
  created_at: 2020-10-24T18:46:59.000Z,
  updated_at: null,
  project: [
    Project {
      id: 1,
      company_id: 1,                    <========= this is required
      name: 'project 1',
      created_at: 2020-10-24T18:47:35.000Z,
      updated_at: null
    },
    Project {
      id: 2,
      company_id: 1,
      name: 'project 1',
      created_at: 2020-10-24T19:08:08.000Z,
      updated_at: null
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the fireld 'company_id' you are not supposed to get the id field of company, as it is the company object itself. So from that object you may get its id. I think that if you would set 'eager: true' on the field, you will get the object in the query, because the default is eager: false.

If what you want is only the id and not the whole object, maube think of a field which is a foreign key to the company id using one-to-one relation, which will give you your wanted reault output

Comment: setting eager to true did nothing and can not use one-to-one relation either as the schema is designed as company will have many projects, i will then have to process the raw data from getRawAndEntities() result set. Thanks @adamC :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to split that up like this. `companyId` will automatically be extracted from `company`.

```
// ...

@ManyToOne(type => Company, company => company.project)
company: Company;

@Column({nullable: true})
companyId: number;

// ...
```

Comment: i will check this and get back thanks @Zammy